# Strange behavior of jQuery css(width)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the width of the first `.imagen` element and give it to `img` inside `.imagen`.

HTML:

```
<div class="imagen">
    <div class="normal">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="hover">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ancho = parseFloat($('.imagen').css("width"));
  console.log(ancho);
  $('.normal img').css("width", ancho);
  $('.hover img').css("width", ancho);
});
```

**PROBLEM:**

For big viewport widths, everything works fine, but for viewports near of 900px wide there is a difference between real `.imagen` width and the width obtained by jQuery.

Here is the .image width (229px):

[image: 227px wide of div .image]

And here is the width obtained by jQuery (237px):

[image: img element with jQuery width aplied]

**QUESTION:**

Why this difference exists?

**RESOURCES:**

There is a codepen with this example:

https://codepen.io/aitormendez/pen/JpZBKQ

And a (temporary) deployed web page with the same problem:

https://raquelfriera.e451.net/

Comment: To reproduce that. Which browser do you use?

Comment: I tryed Firefox and Chrome. Both show the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

jquery does the calculation correct. If you set .imagen with css to overflow:hidden it will show the hover-effect like it should. This means now your images do overlap the div.imagen.

If I set .imagen img to width:100% !important to overwrite the img inline style="width: 265px;" it works. There is something wrong with the inline style width of the images.

Comment: Good catch. To set `.imagen` to `overflow:hidden` hides the excedent of img element but the difference between `.imagen` width and `img`width remains, that is the question :)

Comment: To set img to `width:100% !important` solve the problem of make a rollover hiding part of the image, thank you very much, but not answer the question really. Difference between `.imagen` width and `img` width remains.

Comment: parseFloat has nothing to do with jquery that is javascript. So if you do it with a resize function?

Comment: Ok, thanks! I know the problem. I'll post my answer in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your padding in `.imagen`. Use `.innerWidth()` instead of `.css("width")` to get your width for `ancho`. Have a look at [this updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyzOgN).

Comment: Thank you for try it. In your codepen the problem remains. Also, `innerWidth`is not possible because `box-size: border-box` https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solve it in my head (not in practice yet). But I'm sure about the problem.

The backend is made with WordPress and WP doesn't allow me to build two image sizes with same width. So, two images for the rollover (inside `.normal`and inside `.hover`) has slightly different sizes. Second case (`img` inside `.hover`) is a bit bigger. When jQuery try to get `.imagen` width, this width is the same as big image. Then, all images are resized by jQuery with this size.

To solve it, I just must to make second `img` slightly smaller instead bigger.

My appologies for introduce this weird question and thank you very much to everybody for the help.